NEXT.JS: Property 'data' is missing in type 'Course[]' but required in type 'ResponseData'
Recently been trying out typescript, I came across this error.
I am fetching from an api an array of courses, the api response is an array of objects.
I GET an error saying:

Property 'data' is missing in type 'Course[]' but required in type 'ResponseData'.
HERE ->  const response: ResponseData = await courseRepository.listCourses();

The api response:
data:
[  
0: {uid: 'jj1', code: '001', name: 'Programme Course And Coordinating', description: '(No Description Provided)', enabled: true, …}
1: {uid: 'jj2', code: '002', name:  Children ', description: '(No Description Provided)', enabled: true, …}
2: {uid: 'jj3', code: '003', name: 'Equipment ', description: '(No Description Provided)', enabled: true, …} 
]

I created this interfaces:
interface Course {
uid: string;
code: string;
name: string;
description: string;
created_at: Date;
last_modified_at: Date;
// relations
schedules?: CourseSchedule[];
}

interface ResponseData {data: Course[];}

and fetch here:
const [courses, setCourses] = useState<Course[]>([]); //  const courseRepository = useCourseRepository(apiClent);
    
    const allCourses = async () => { try { 
     const response: ResponseData = await courseRepository.listCourses();
        console.log('All Courses');
        console.log(response);
        setCourses(response.data);
        console.log(courses);
    
        // toast('Success');
    } catch (error) {
        const apiError = error;
        console.log('Api Error!');
        console.log(apiError);
        // toast('Invalid UserName or Password' + apiError);
    }
};\`


I tried so many fixes all to no avail. I just need to get rid of the error, so I can run build.

This question has severe formatting problems.

@Jerry made some fixes, please check

I am not expert in TS nor React, so I cannot help you. Moreover I think you will have to also add fiddle / online example.
